# Is my device infected/hacked?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

Today on a normal navigation with firefox a fake popup said

"your firefox is infected with 2 virus"

then android ask me to give to firefox the "vibration access" of course i refuse.
And then firefox ask me to going to google-play to download antivirus.

I deinstall firefox and reinstall..and the page with advice disappear.

I download then the "free antivirus" from google-play(not the antivirus wich firefox want to force me to download) and do a scan..no virus found.

But now with linux I do a nmap on android device..and port 554(rstp) tcp
is open!
Why is open?Is my device infected or what else?

Comment: Never believe adds that pretend your phone has been infected!

Comment: Delete the browser cache and it probably will vanish as you discovered after re install. It does not mean that your device infected. You may like to run a scan using *Malwarebytes* app from play Store.

Comment: He said 0 malaware

Comment: it can be their as the websites can exploit stagefright bug and infect it and antivirus might not know it

Comment: 554 or 5554 (port)?

Comment: 554 sure,telnet 554 and nmap confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found,there is something strange on my net because i see 554 port on every machine!

But if i did a telnet outside this machine..554 doesn't answer.

I investigate..meanwhile i'm happy my android is not infected,firefox probably take a fake virus.